# callto: Unsafe - Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, call, skype

I want on click to do a `skype` call which actually works if i hard coded the value, but if I bind the value I get `callto: Unsafe` How can I do this with simple logic ?

Here is my HTML

```
  <a ng-href="callto://{{contact[0].phone_no}}">{{contact[0].phone_no}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to white list the **'callto protocol'** in compileProvider,

you can add it on appConfig see the example below

```
myAngularApp.config(['$compileProvider', function( $compileProvider) {


$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https|ftp|mailto|callto):/);

}];
```

**EDIT**

if your browser is not supportin callto try it with tel

```
  <a ng-href="tel://{{contact[0].phone_no}}">{{contact[0].phone_no}}</a></li>

 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https|ftp|mailto|tel):/);
```

NOTE : the end user  can change the Default app

see

[chrome://settings/handlers](http://chrome://settings/handlers) in chrome

and  Control Panel ->  Default Programs in windows

Comment: Applied your answer, skype does open but the call does not go

Comment: is usafe is removed from url ..?

Comment: Yes it has been removed

Comment: Thats all, if skype isnt opened it depends on your default program setting,

Comment: callto: is not standard protocol, i recommend you to use tel: instead of callto: